# table partitioning and mysql ndb cluster

Tags: mysql, replication, partitioning, database-partitioning, mysql-cluster

I have mysql ndb cluster with 3 datanodes. I want to break one of my tables into partitions based on one column (maybe date), the question is that what happens after I run partitioning script :

- I will have all partitions of the table on every 3 datanodes?
- each datanode will hold a fraction of table (one or two of partitions)?
- could I choose one of aforementioned options?

Comment: More importantly, will you get any benefit?

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 data nodes I presume you have 3 replicas. In that case
all data is replicated on all nodes.

NDB only supports hash partitioning, so in order to have any kind of date
partitioning, you need some clever hash value put into a partitioning column
based on the date.